# How to treat remote txt file as stream?

Tags: text-processing, remote, curl, http

A web service writes its output in a text file.

I can fetch that log via:

```
curl -u user:password -k https://log.my-app.com/log.2016-04-04.txt
```

Yet this always only fetches a current "full" file even though it is still being written to.

I want to fetch the remote txt file as if it was a stream and have it constantly refetch itself after one minute but only show the updated content.

Is something like this possible using curl?

Comment: I bet there is a recipe using rsync that would suit this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `-C --continue-at` and `-f --fail` arguments.

```
curl -f -# -u user:password -k -C - -O https://log.my-app.com/log.2016-04-04.txt
```

Without `-f` the output file will be appended with html from the 416 (invalid range) error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `curl -C -` in a loop to get it to fetch only what has been added, and use `tail -f` on the local file to watch for the new data. The remote server has to allow for this sort of access.

If it does not, use `N=$(stat -c %s file)` on the local file to find its size, then pipe the curl through `tail -c +N | tee -a file` to get the new stuff to the file and stdout.